# Replace specific datetime values with string value in column full of mixed datatypes with pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, replace

I have survey data where some of the answers that were reporting a range of users were converted to datetime. In my dataframe my ['Answer'] column has all the survey answers which is a mix of datatypes and is classified as object.

I have tried converting the column to str as below

```
dataset_merged['Answer'].astype(str, errors='ignore')
dataset_merged['Answer'].dtypes

Output: dtype('O')
```

Which still results in the object dtype. I have also tried replacing the datetime answers directly:

```
dataset_merged['Answer'].replace({
    '2022-01-05 00:00:00' : '1 - 5',
    '2022-10-20 00:00:00' : '10 - 20',
    '2022-05-10 00:00:00' : '5 - 10'
}, inplace=True)
```

Which also doesn't work. Any suggestions on this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: hi, perhaps it should be the key should be a datetime object?

Comment: you have to assign it back like: `dataset_merged['Answer']=dataset_merged['Answer'].astype(str)`